# Is there a bug in "tf add /recursive"?

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I'm trying to add the following folder tree to TFS:

```
C:\TFS\folder1
C:\TFS\folder1\folder2
C:\TFS\folder1\folder2\folder3
C:\TFS\folder1\folder2\folder3\test.txt
```

In the above example the folder "C:\TFS" is a mapped TFS working folder. I issue the following commands from the console:

```
cd C:\TFS
tf add folder1 /recursive
```

After this command has finished my repository contains the following tree (as pending changes):

```
$/folder1
$/folder1/folder2
```

As you can see "folder3" and the text file "test.txt" below are completely missing! Why?

**Update:** I've submitted this as a bug to Microsoft:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=423279

Answer (score 0):

worked for me.

```
c:\Temp>md Test\1\2\3\4\5

c:\Temp>dir test /s/b
c:\Temp\test\1
c:\Temp\test\1\2
c:\Temp\test\1\2\3
c:\Temp\test\1\2\3\4
c:\Temp\test\1\2\3\4\5

c:\Temp>cd test

c:\Temp\Test>tf add 1 /recursive
1

1:
2

1\2:
3

1\2\3:
4

1\2\3\4:
5

c:\Temp\Test>
```

In Tfs
[image: TFS Tree View]

Same if I do it from Test or above Test directory

Comment: Well, it doesn't for me! Did you set your working directory to "C:\Temp"? No matter what I try, tf.exe only adds two levels.

Comment: I think so -if you look above I did a "cd test". Temp is in the workspace. Also like I said I've tried it from Temp directory too. The same results. Just a thought I'm use TFS 2008 with VS2008 + Team Explorer 2008 SP1.

Comment: I used Team Explorer 2005 and 2008 (both latest service pack I think, although I will check that). I'm not sure about the TFS version, but I'll check that too.

Answer (score 0):

from microsoft the basic command goes as follows:

```
tf add itemspec [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/type:filetype] 
[/noprompt] [/recursive] [/login:username,[password]]
```

I typed in the following command and it worked fine:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" add itemspec /r "where to add to"
```

you run the command from the folder you want to copy files and in the command under "where to add to" you type the destination